# Trying to use ansible replace module to update multiple lines in file and remain idempotent

Tags: replace, ansible

Code I have is not working:

```
---
- hosts: '{{ target }}'
  tasks:
    - name: Search for strings in file.
      replace:
        path: /home/jay/tasks.conf
        regexp: '(^\s*$)# End of file'
        replace: |-

          make_bed
          brush_teeth
          # End of file
```

The one constant I know is that the bottom of the current file is a blank line followed by '# End of file'

I'm trying to get that block replaced so it looks like following:

```
<blank line>
make_bed
brush_teeth
# End of file
```

It becomes idempotent because once this is in place it won't match a blank line followed by '# End of file' if I run the script again.

I'm not sure if my regexp is at fault or if I'm doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Please close question.

Needed following:

```
regexp: '(^\s*$)\n^(# End of file)'
```